# I had error after add appwrite to my app ( flutter )

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, appwrite

I didn't add or write anything to code just install appwrite and added to my app and This error appeared

THE ERROR :

```
lib/tempCodeRunnerFile.dart:1:1: Error: Expected a declaration, but got ''package:device_info_plus/src/device_info_plus_web.dart''.
'package:device_info_plus/src/device_info_plus_web.dart'
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

[Done] exited with code=254 in 0.564 seconds
```

and there is 3 problems in generated_plugin_registrant.dart

I didnot try anything because I do not know what is wrong I did not add letter to code just install appwrite

Comment: What version of the appwrite package did you install and what version of flutter do you have?